# How to use ArrayList[] - Array of ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist

Well, this is somewhat stupid question but I want to explore something new that's why posting this question. Please! before marking it duplicate or irrelevant post your answer.

Q: How to use Array of ArrayList specially when the ArrayList is in other class and Array of ArrayList in main()?

```
class ArrayListDemo {

private ArrayList<Type> arrList = new ArrayList<Type>();

public void addItem(Type x) { 
       arrList.add(x);
       System.out.println("Type Added: " + x);
    }
}
```

Now, main() is like:

```
public void main(String[] args) {
       ArrayListDemo[] arr = new ArrayListDemo[10];
       Type x = somethingSilly;
       arr[0].addItem(x);      // <-- java.lang.NullPointerException
}
```

What I'm missing or what's wrong with this?
I know, there are better options like available List<> etc but I'm given a task to do it just via Array of ArrayList.

Comment: The code is confusing. classes have to be written starting with an Upercase: so it is class ArrayListDemo. edit your code and question

Comment: @AlexWien they actually don't have to but I agree that they should be.

Comment: @AlexWien they don't have to, however it's preferable because it's improves code readability.

Comment: The term "have to" is not releated to the compiler, but to recomended minimum java style.

Comment: Sir, this is just a sample code. In actual code, everything is perfect regarding "Naming Convention".

Comment: When you create an array  
`arrayListDemo[] arr = new arrayListDemo[10];`

All 10 locations of `arr` are null since you did not initialize it with an object. It is just giving you 10 pointers where you can store references to `arrayListDemo` type object.

You need to create an object of `arrayListDemo` like this:  
`arr[0] = new arrayListDemo()`

Then you can call `arr[0].addItem(x);`

Comment: @ashutosh: This worked... ThumpUp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arr[0]` is null because you didn't populate the array. Example population code:

```
for ( ArrayList< Type > list : arr)
        list = new ArrayList< Type >( );
```

Comment: I didn't get it. Where this should be done? In main() or in class?

Comment: @I_have_No_Life after you initialize (create) `arr` variable but before you interact with it (`arr.something()`).

Answer (score 0):

Because:

```
arrayListDemo[] arr = new arrayListDemo[10];
```

Just creates a 10-element array of `arrayListDemo`s, but doesn't actually allocate anything, so the value for each element is the default of `null`.